# enable eSIM in samsung s21 FE?

Tags: android-12, samsung

I am trying to enable eSIM on S21 FE 5G european distribution [Snapdragon].
Device model: SM-G990B /DS
Android 12, one UI 4.1
I rooted the Phone but cannot figure out which file to modify in android 12.
i saw that some solution working for s20 series with lower (rooted) android versions but i didn't find android 10 or 11 firmware for this model online.

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you figured it out.  I also got a S21 FE 5G couple months ago.  Through some research on the net, I don't think it supports eSim now.

This is in Samsung community: https://eu.community.samsung.com/t5/galaxy-s21-series/s21-fe-5g-esim/td-p/5817737